# c# interop with unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, dll, cuda

What I am trying to make is a CUDA accelerated fractal generator. I want to use c# to create the ui, but the fractal images are being generated by unmanaged cuda c compiled in a dll. Following some tutorials, I have managed to make interop work with simple data, but I am having difficulty creating the bitmap image and passing it back to the c# application.

I can put together a buffer in the dll with the pixel data succesfully using CUDA, but how can I use the pointer to that buffer to make a bitmap in the c sharp application?

Comment: Can you post some code showing the bitmap you want C# to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One out of some ways to do that:

If your native function looks like:

```
void foo(void *bitmap);
```

You can use P/Invoke to declare:

```
[DllImport(...)]
public static unsafe void foo(void *bitmap);
```

and then use it as follows:

```
unsafe
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[...];
    fixed (void *pBuffer = buffer)
    {
        foo(pBuffer);
    }
}
```

Notice that you should allow unsafe code (in the project settings, Build tab).

Comment: Thank you. Follow up question, how would I use that buffer to create a bitmap image that I can use for a pictureBox? Sorry if this question seems dumber than the first one but I'm new to c#.

Comment: I'm not sure how you do that in WinForms. I see that the PictureBox control has a property named Image which yous should set. You can create an Image object from byte array as explained here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv